# Extracting part of the string using Ansible regex_search and save the output as a variable

Tags: ansible, regex, ansible-playbook, regular-expressions

I'm having a content like below inside a file.

```
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
4lw.commands.whitelist=mntr,conf,ruok,stat
syncLimit=2
```

I wanted to read the value for ***dataDir*** using Ansible and set it to a variable. I have written following code but regular expression and storing the variable both have some issues.

```
  - name: Read zoo.cfg content
    shell:
      cmd: cat zoo.cfg
    register: zoo_config_content

  - set_fact:
      my_var: "{{ zoo_config_content.stdout | regex_search('dataDir.*')}}"

  - name: Print
    debug:
      var: my_var
```

Q1.) How can I improve the regular expression to get only ***/var/lib/zookeeper*** ?

Q2.) How can I store that extracted value to use in another task?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one question, add a separate question for your second part. But with `set_fact` you already stored the value and can use it. If you open an additional question please elaborate more what's your problem with that variable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add a group to your regex and a second parameter that specifies which group to return:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ zoo_config_content.stdout | regex_search('dataDir=(.+)', '\\1') | first }}"
```

This would return an array with a single element, so I added `| first` to get only one element directly as a string.

Result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_var": "/var/lib/zookeeper"
}
```

If the config file resides on the Ansible machine you can make it even easier [using a lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html):

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ lookup('file', 'zoo.cfg') | regex_search('dataDir=(.+)', '\\1') | first }}"
```